# chart in excel to represent correlation of 3 parameters

Tags: excel, graph, charts, correlation

Please dont eat me because of this question :)

I have some data in excel and I would like to make a graphical representation of those data. Structure of my data:

persons ID : from 1 to 485 to every person, there is one parameter like average jumping distance and another parameter (like height) and finally there is a class to which every person belongs to (1, 2 or 3).

To assign persons to classes I have used k-means algorithm.

Now I would like to make a graph of this result. How can I do it please in excel (or by using another tool)?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a scatter (XY chart with markers and no lines). Plot average jumping distance on one axis, height on the second axis. Then for the classes I would separate all the data into 3 series and use different colors for each series. I would adjust the marker size to see which one works best with the data.

Here is a fast example to give you an idea how to it would look like. Its not as easy as just clicking once to insert the chart from the data though:
[image]

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer. I think this might be what I was looking for, but can you please help me and tell me how to plot this in excel? In excel I am choosing both columns and then XY scatter point chart. However it is not putting one column in one axis and other column on other axis. I already have 2 colors points on the graph. One color for heights and other for jumping. I really dont know how to solve this. Thank you

Comment: You can see how to add multiple series to a chart here for example: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DMlfxsNdaNc